What happens with the ideals when the product of C*-algebra is altered?
Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algerba and $u$ be an element of $A$ of norm $1$. Define a new product on $A$ as $a.b=aub$ then $A$ is a Banach $*$-algebra with this new product. If $I$ is an ideal with old product then it is clear that $I$ is an ideal with new product too.

Given an ideal $I$ with new product, can we construct a non zero ideal with old product?


Yes, the zero ideal. Please specify what you really want.

@MartinBrandenburg: I am trying to see the changes in class of ideals with new product.

To get a Banach $\ast$-algebra, you need $u$ to be self-adjoint, as otherwise you won’t have $(a.b)^\ast = b^\ast.a^\ast$.

No. In fact, $A$ can be simple under the old product but not simple under the new one. For example, $A = M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is simple. If $u = e_{11}$, then under the new product $I = \mathbb{C}e_{22}$ is a nonzero proper ideal.

Thank you so much.
